# PHP, can't use xml array (simplexml)

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

I have an rss in xml form with  who contain  (well formatted)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("/rss.xml");
echo $xml->item[0]->guid;
```

This code give me nothing.
If I `var_dump` the `$xml`, I get 40  array.

Can someone guess why?

var_dump:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["version"]=>
    string(3) "2.0"
  }
  ["channel"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (6) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(11) "example.com"
    ["link"]=>
    string(23) "http://www.example.com/"
    ["description"]=>
    string(43) "Example free hosting for free unicorn videos."
    ["lastBuildDate"]=>
    string(31) "Mon, 18 Nov 2013 05:03:00 +0100"
    ["ttl"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["item"]=>
    array(40) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (5) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(23) "..."
        ["description"]=>
        string(766) ".. "
        ["link"]=>
        string(59) "http://www.example.com/..."
        ["guid"]=>
        string(12) "video5748963"
        ["pubDate"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#43 (0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (5) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(48) "...s"
        ["description"]=>
        string(789) "..."
        ["link"]=>
        string(84) "http://www.example.com/,,,"
        ["guid"]=>
        string(12) "video4863479"
        ["pubDate"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#43 (0) {
        }
      }
 ....
```

Comment: show your dump. And your XML

Comment: uh that doesn't sound right :s

Comment: edited with infos, mostly NSFW so care.

Comment: you should remove the porn links, is it an ad or a real question ?
you are accessing the xml->item but items is in xml->channel->item, maybe the issue is here

Comment: As you can see in your `var_dump`, your `item` is not a direct child of `$xml`.  `echo $xml->channel->item[0]->guid;`.

Comment: Edited the nsfw part, I didn't post them for a reason and yes it's a real question.
I see, thx for the help I'm tired sorry :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like

```
$xml->channel->item[1]->guid
```

that gets you the guid.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure of a typical RSS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        ...
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        ...
    </channel>
</rss>
```

In your call, you have to omit the top level node (`<rss>` in this case) but not second level nodes:

```
echo $xml->item[0]->guid; // <channel>?
```